# Mongoid: Sorting by two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

This might be an odd one, but I've got documents with two dates.  `created_at` and `featured_at`.

I want to sort by `featured_at` first, then `created_at`.  Though when I do something as simple as `.desc(:featured_at, :created_at)`, I get all the featured first, and the rest afterward.

In ruby, I'd sort by `[featured_at, created_at].max` but I need to do this on the db side.

Any tips?  Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure of the ruby syntax, but in general you can use: db.coll.find(<query>).sort({ featured_at : 1, created_at : 1 })

Comment: Isn't that the same of `desc(:featured_at, :created_at)`?

Comment: I guess yes, but if I am not wrong, what you are telling "sort by featured_at first, then created_at." just means "sort by created_at" ultimately. Let me know if I understood the ques wrong

Comment: Yeah, I assumed with `featured_at` being nil, it would prefer `created_at` in those cases.  But it sorts them ALL by `featured_at`, then `created_at` within those.  So a giant group of nil `featured_at` with all the `created_at` in order in there.

Comment: Essentially I want a "sort by the greater of the two".  Perhaps can be done in mapreduce?  Never done sorting with that.

Comment: "sort by the greater of the two", I would have recommended that while inserting the document, insert a extra field which is the max of the two, so that you can easily index it and the queries will be fast.

Comment: Yeah, that's smart.  Just store `sort_date`.  Is it possible to sort in mapreduce out of curiosity?

Comment: I have not used mapreduce much, but there are many google results for mapreduce with sort.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's outside of the scope of map reduce (http://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2011-02/msg00441.html)

Comment: So I guess the best thing to do is to create a `sort_date` - If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept that.

Comment: Posting it as answer, so that other viewers can take benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that while inserting the document, insert a extra field which is the max of the two, so that you can easily index it and the queries will be fast.